# Failed to resolved google service

Tags: android

I need to add dependencies "implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'"
but this pic shows up[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use below line with "play-services-clearcut" version 15.0.1:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-clearcut:15.0.1'
```

instead of

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-clearcut:16.0.0'
```